# How to use varifocal loss in YOLOv5?

Tags: loss-function, loss, yolov5

I'm a beginner in modifying YOLOv5 and I'd like to know how to detailed steps to use the varifocal loss from VarifocalNet and implement it to YOLOv5 (pytorch).

I putted a link here below which is the python file of the varifocal loss

[Varifocal Loss](https://github.com/hyz-xmaster/VarifocalNet/blob/f459696240b4442b75bcebbbe4f0910ee4e0f66b/mmdet/models/losses/varifocal_loss.py)

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

1. copy builder and utils file from the following repository

https://github.com/hyz-xmaster/VarifocalNet

yow will find the builder file [builder](https://github.com/hyz-xmaster/VarifocalNet/tree/master/mmdet/models) here and  [utils](https://github.com/hyz-xmaster/VarifocalNet/tree/master/mmdet/models/losses) here. Then paste these two files in yolov5 "utils".

2. pip install mmcv [you can find here](https://pypi.org/project/mmcv/)
3. Pasts the following code [Varifocal](https://github.com/hyz-xmaster/VarifocalNet/blob/f459696240b4442b75bcebbbe4f0910ee4e0f66b/mmdet/models/losses/varifocal_loss.py) in the "loss.py" file. ( you can put below QFocalLoss Class).
4. Remove one dot (.) before builder in Varifocal code. Meaning that put `from .builder import LOSSES` instead `from ..builder import LOSSES` (because we put builder file in same folder)
5. Use these three lines:

Use this :

```
g = 2  # focal loss gamma
if g > 0:
    BCEcls, BCEobj = VarifocalLoss(BCEcls), VarifocalLoss(BCEobj)
```

Instead of :

```
g = h['fl_gamma']  # focal loss gamma
if g > 0:
    BCEcls, BCEobj = FocalLoss(BCEcls, g), FocalLoss(BCEobj, g)
```